# Why are function-like macros evaluated in Normal-Order in C?

Tags: c, macros

The C Program given below:

```
#define p(x) (printf("%d ", x))
#define q(a,b,c) ({int total = a; printf("%d ", b); total += c;})
int main(){
    q(p(1), 2, p(3));
}
```

Produces the output `1 2 3`, showing that a Normal Order evaluation was used. However, for normal functions in, such as this snippet:

```
int p(int i){
    printf("%d ", i);
    return i;
}

void q(int a, int b, int c){
    int total = a;
    printf("%d ", b);
    total += c;
}
int main(){
    q(p(1), 2, p(3));
}
```

the output is `1 3 2`, implying that an applicative-order evaluation is used. What is the underlying basis for this behavior? How are the arguments of a macro evaluated as compared to a function?

Comment: Why not should they be?

Comment: Compile with `-E`, know the power of the preprocessor.

Comment: I'm not convinced `p(x)`, as shown here, does what you think it does.

Comment: so that's just the way things are? any efficiency arguments?

Comment: Remember, macros are a literal text substitution. You can either perform that substitution by hand or ask the compiler to show you what it has done. Looking at that, and the sequence points in the expansion, should answer your question.

Comment: when calling a function ,`q()` in the second example, the functions that are the parameters are executed and the returned value is passed to the function: `q()`.   This is very different from the `q` macro which is a text substitution and then executed.  Expanding the macro by hand (or use the -E parameter on the compile step) would make it obvious what is actually happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macros arguments are fully expanded before the evaluation, so the compiler will evaluate the macros in the order p, p, q. However the code is not actually executed at this stage, merely expanded as text.

So your first example will expand to:

```
int main() {
    ({int total = (printf("%d", 1); printf("%d", 2); total += printf("%d", 3);});
}
```

This is then compiled according to normal c rules as a sequence of statements.

With functions, the compiler generates the code for each function separately, then places calls where they are used. This means it has to know the value of the arguments to q, before it can call q.